# Regexp metachars "*" and "*?" in the JAVA's replaceAll() method behave oddly

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String.replaceAll() anomaly with greedy quantifiers in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604286/string-replaceall-anomaly-with-greedy-quantifiers-in-regex)
>   [Strange behavior in regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228509/strange-behavior-in-regexes)

While

```java
"a".replaceAll("a", "b")
"a".replaceAll("a+", "b")
"a".replaceAll("a+?", "b")
```

all return `b`, why does

```java
"a".replaceAll("a*", "b")
```

return `bb` and

```java
"a".replaceAll("a*?", "b")
```

return `bab`?

Comment: still searching for the duplicate...

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228509/strange-behavior-in-regexes

Comment: I think Perl returns bbb in the second case. That makes more sense. a*? not matching 'a' is weird.

Comment: @jdb The link I posted explains this well I think.

Comment: echo a | perl -i -pe "s/a*?/b/g"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
"a".replaceAll("a*", "b")
```

First replaces `a` to `b`, then advances the pointer past the `b`. Then it matches the end of string, and replaces with `b`. Since it matched an empty string, it advances the pointer, falls out of the string, and finishes, resulting in `bb`.

```
"a".replaceAll("a*?", "b")
```

first matches the start of string and replaces with `b`. It doesn't match the `a` because `?` in `a*?` means "non-greedy" (match as little as possible). Since it matched an empty string, it advances the pointer, skipping `a`. Then it matches the end of string, replaces with `b` and falls out of the string, resulting in `bab`. The end result is the same as if you did `"a".replaceAll("", "b")`.

Comment: @mikeslattery If the pointer didn't advance, then the replacer would be stuck in an infinite loop anytime you matched an empty string.

Comment: That prints bbb. It seems more logical to me: 
echo a | perl -i -pe "s/a*?/b/g"

Comment: @jdb what are the rules in perl? If a match is empty, the pointer doesn't move but the next match is restricted to be non-empty with the usual rules of backtracking the last group first?

Comment: Advancing to the next character because the empty space was a match explains the problem but does not make it right. I don't know what the Perl rules are but it just make more sense. Python has the same bug.

Comment: @jdb I wouldn't call it a bug. It does make sense and it's definitely intentional. Javascript behaves as Java (skips a character).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I agree with @jbd, it would make more sense to me if `a*?` on `a` returned `bbb`.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because of zero-width matches.

```
"a".replaceAll("a*", "b")
```

Will match two times:

1. Try match at beginning of the string, greedy `*` consumes the `a` as a match.
2. Advance to the next position in the string (now at end of string), try match there, empty string matches.

   ```
   " a "
    \| \___ 2. match empty string
     \_____ 1. match "a"
   ```

```
"a".replaceAll("a*?", "b")
```

Will also match two times:

1. Try match at beginning of the string, non-greedy `*?` matches the empty string without consuming the `a`.
2. Advance to next position in the string (now at end of string), try match there, empty string matches.

   ```
   " a "
    \  \___ 2. match empty string
     \_____ 1. match empty string
   ```

Comment: I like the diagrams `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

in `"a".replaceAll("a*", "b")`

```
* - for 0 or more so here in `a*`
```

```
1. a - replaced by b
2. * - is also true as empty string is true for *,so, replaced by b
```

and in `"a".replaceAll("a*?", "b")`

```
1. *? - makes anything non-greedy means it makes regrex to match as little
        as possible,
2. so,the pre and post empty string would be replaced by "b" and 
   as a*? is non-greedy, it will not replace it
```